# Hibernate restore error OSX 10.11.4

Tags: macos, ssd, sleep, hibernate, kernel-panic

I have MacBook Pro mid2012,
after upgrade SSD+HDD+RAM I noticed that after few hours in sleep, osx cannot wake up, I see hibernate restore process, but after couple seconds osx drops into panic.

Thoughts SSD problem, so I turned off Standby function, did not helps
Also I set Hibernate Mode - 0, same story

here is the panic

```
Anonymous UUID:       161DF0FE-D26B-13C4-EA0D-E3CC69AF0BDC

Sun Mar 27 07:31:17 2016

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff802da7c8d8): "Hibernate restore error e00002bf"@/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-3248.40.184/iokit/Kernel/IOHibernateIO.cpp:2320
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff82165d3b10 : 0xffffff802d4dab12 
0xffffff82165d3b90 : 0xffffff802da7c8d8 
0xffffff82165d3c60 : 0xffffff802d5db0cd 
0xffffff82165d3cd0 : 0xffffff7fb014c21f 
0xffffff82165d3d10 : 0xffffff7fb014fa75 
0xffffff82165d3d30 : 0xffffff802dad1352 
0xffffff82165d3d90 : 0xffffff802dafc4f6 
0xffffff82165d3e00 : 0xffffff802daa23a9 
0xffffff82165d3e60 : 0xffffff802da9a334 
0xffffff82165d3ec0 : 0xffffff802daa75f2 
0xffffff82165d3f00 : 0xffffff802daa7742 
0xffffff82165d3f40 : 0xffffff802dab27c1 
0xffffff82165d3f80 : 0xffffff802dab29bc 
0xffffff82165d3fb0 : 0xffffff802d5c8e27 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform(4.0)[A29C7512-D3A8-3AED-9721-3A5FF1A32EB2]@0xffffff7fb0141000->0xffffff7fb01a0fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[5D7574C3-8E90-3873-BAEB-D979FC215A7D]@0xffffff7fadfd4000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[4FE41F9B-2849-322A-BBF8-A94816C003D6]@0xffffff7fadd4d000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
15E65

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 15.4.0: Fri Feb 26 22:08:05 PST 2016; root:xnu-3248.40.184~3/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 4E7B4496-0B81-34E9-97AF-F316103B0839
Kernel slide:     0x000000002d200000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff802d400000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff802d300000
System model name: MacBookPro9,2 (Mac-6F01561E16C75D06)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 50454245820490
last loaded kext at 36958088041335: com.apple.macos.driver.AppleUSBEthernetHost 8.0.1 (addr 0xffffff7fb01c5000, size 49152)
last unloaded kext at 43694099959208: com.apple.macos.driver.AppleUSBEthernetHost   8.0.1 (addr 0xffffff7fb01c5000, size 24576)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.21.18
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   274.7
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   274.7
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.4.4f4
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics   10.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.8.9
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.13
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 10.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    208
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.4.4f4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.0.8
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  245.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 245.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  327.5
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 38
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.8.5
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.2
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.7.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.8
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   1040.1.1a6
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.2.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCIPCI    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   163
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 274.7
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    525
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   108.2.1
com.apple.driver.CoreCaptureResponder   1
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.14d1
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    205.3
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.12.6
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 274.7
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 274.7
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   204.3
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.14d1
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d7
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.4.4f4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.4.4f4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.7
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 250.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  900.4.1
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    517.20.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.8.1
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1110.26
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCI   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 417.2
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that particular panic usually indicates a file read error when trying to read the sleepimage while restoring from hibernation. Which drive are you booting from, an SSD or an HDD? Which drive is your `/var/vm/sleepimage` stored on? If you manually duplicate your `/var/vm/sleepimage`, can you successfully copy the whole thing? Have you run diags on your drives? Have you made sure you don't have any bad sectors or "pending" sectors?